# Is there really a valid code-path where this function won't return a value?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, csc

I have the below function that iterates over a list of workers, invoking their DoStuff() method. If the first worker fails, I try the next one until I'm out of workers. If they all fail, I re-throw the last exception.

```
// workers is an IList<>.
public object TryDoStuff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < workers.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return worker[i].DoStuff();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (i == workers.Count - 1)
            {
                throw; // This preserves the stack trace
            }
            else
            {
                continue; // Try the next worker
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get an error that "not all code paths return a value" for this function. Although I can silence the error by adding an explicit return after the for loop, I'm doubting the compiler is accurate here as I don't see how the for loop will be escaped without either returning or re-throwing an exception. And if an exception is re-thrown, not returning a value is valid.

What am I missing? Is csc unable to reason about the conditional in the catch block?

Comment: Maybe your answer is: What will be happen if the count of the workers list items be zero?

Comment: Ugh. So obvious. Thanks folks.

Comment: Craig, I wrote more detail in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544729/is-there-really-a-valid-code-path-where-this-function-wont-return-a-value/55544910#55544910) too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

1. If there is an exception thrown on the last index and count isn't what you expect it to be (unlikely yet possible)
2. Or as [RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1474613/ra) pointed out if `Count` is zero

In this case, the static analysis and subsequent compiler error is very justified

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, if workers is empty (Count is 0), there's no valid return path.

There's also another race condition (depending on the full context, obviously) where `workers` is not empty, an exception is thrown on an element, there are still elements to iterate in `workers`, **but** after evaluating `if (i == workers.Count - 1)` and **before** the `continue` statement executes, another thread removes elements from `workers` (or changes the entire `workers` variable to a new instance).

In that scenario, the `for` condition will return false on the next iteration unexpectedly and you'll fall out of the loop with no return statement for the method.

```
public object TryDoStuff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < workers.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return worker[i].DoStuff();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (i == workers.Count - 1)
            {
                throw; // This preserves the stack trace
            }
            else
            {
                // XXX If workers is changed by another thread here. XXX
                continue; // Try the next worker
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote as a comment for you:

> What will be happen if the **count of the workers list items** be
>   **zero**?

It seems this is the compiler question and it dose not do more research about your code! :)

Actually **this reason is enough for compiler** to show the bellow error to you

> not all code paths return a value

When the compiler encounters with a loop in the whole of the body of a method it assume that the loop condition cause that the loop body be ignored then it expected any value out of the loop too.

Yes, even if we set the condition of the loop at the way that the loop be executed!

**Proof:**

With error:

```
public static object TryDoStuff()
{
    var result =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Add 100 unit");
            result += 100;
            return result;
    }   

    //Console.WriteLine("last line");
//  return result;
}
```

Without error:

```
public static object TryDoStuff()
{
    var result =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Add 100 unit");
            result += 100;
            // return result; you can un-comment this line too
    }   

    Console.WriteLine("last line");
    return result;
}
```